# Wrong layout on Android tablet

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On the Stack Exchange app for Android I get a really annoying layout bug so that I can't really use the app.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

It only happens in the Question/Answer view. Not in the latest questions, etc.
It doesn't matter if landscape or portrait.

I don't know if that happens on any other tablet. On my smartphone everything runs fine.

My device is a ODYS Union 10 with a resolution of 1280x800 and Android 4.2.2.

Comment: What happens if you pull to refresh the page? Does this happen on every page?

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: No one who has the same problem?

Comment: We've had one other person on our team reproduce the problem, I haven't been able to yet on any of my devices but we're still keeping an eye out.

Comment: Any news on it?

Comment: This *might* be fixed in the next update. We had a similar bug when testing the app out on the newest android developer preview, and I fixed it for that. I haven't been able to recreate it on a prior version of Android yet so I don't know if it's the same issue you had.

Comment: Ah okay, i will tell you when it's out.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi looks like it's fixed indeed, [tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent update solved the problem.