# Pinch Zoom on Android app, please?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Very often screen shots are too small to see on tablets. Text is also sometimes a problem.

So can we please have a Pinch Zoom?

Answer (score 1):

You can tap on an image and the image will open in a call out box similar to tapping on code blocks. Once in that call out box, you can pinch to zoom the image.

[Text being too small has been brought up previously, unsure about a resolution on that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234531/wrong-layout-on-android-tablet)